# How to parse this kind of string?

Tags: c#

I am getting an output in the below format

```
                            size client                                 ssflags                                 group                                   flags                                                 date     time                                                level volume                                               ss completed              name
                       290502556 awsknwpi00                             vrF                                     BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION                    cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:56:29 PM                                    full AFTD-Bootstrap-00                                        10/05/2018 07:56:36 PM bootstrap  
                       916940228 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:28 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:17:52 PM C:\
                            5016 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:34 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:07:51 PM F:\
                       579984280 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:24 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:17:48 PM VSS SYSTEM FILESET:\
                        35291616 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:53 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:09:30 PM VSS SYSTEM BOOT:\
                       638349452 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:20 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:03 PM VSS SYSTEM FILESET:\
                      2774969836 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                             AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:11 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:30:45 PM D:\
                       743703956 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                             AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:10 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:30:54 PM E:\
                       410140044 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                             AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:09 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:45 PM F:\
                        71691676 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                              GIS Servers_Dup                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 01:00:08 AM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 01:00:48 AM VSS SYSTEM SERVICES:\
                        15075028 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vrF                            AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:17:24 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:17:53 PM \\?\VOLUME{2186CF2E-5D39-11DF-9211-806E6F6E6963}\
                         3562216 aunswpfilv03.production.transfieldservices.com vF                              GIS Servers_Dup                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 01:01:05 AM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 01:06:05 AM D:\
                      1382628028 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:17 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:38 PM C:\
                               4 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:18 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:07:37 PM P:\
                       258436476 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vrF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:16 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:07:55 PM \\?\VOLUME{CE3268A4-79C3-11E6-8138-806E6F6E6963}\
                               4 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:19 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:07:38 PM D:\
                           21956 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:17 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:07:33 PM E:\
                         3922628 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:29 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:48 PM WINDOWS ROLES AND FEATURES:\
                       258436476 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vrF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:18 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:08:05 PM \\?\VOLUME{15D9292D-7A06-11E6-8138-806E6F6E6963}\
                       258436476 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vrF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:07:40 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:08:35 PM \\?\VOLUME{15D9292D-7A06-11E6-8138-806E6F6E6963}\
                      1153400396 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:09 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:30:18 PM C:\
                      1321796176 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vF                                AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:16 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:35:19 PM C:\
                        15075028 aunnd.production.transfservices.com vrF                               AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cr                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:15 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:09:46 PM \\?\VOLUME{AEF6A4F6-4DC8-11E0-92F6-806E6F6E6963}\
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:10:19 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:21 PM /bin
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:10:36 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:44 PM /boot
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:10:27 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:30 PM /cgroup
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:25 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:28 PM /dev
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:12 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:15 PM /etc
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:13 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:17 PM /lib64
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:10:48 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:57 PM /lost+found
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:06 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:18 PM /media
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:47 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:51 PM /media
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:57 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:02 PM /mnt
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:10:41 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:11:46 PM /net
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:27 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:31 PM /net
                         1707740 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:29 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:35 PM /nsr/cache
                           78220 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:09 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:09:12 PM /nsr/logs
                           84084 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:34 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:39 PM /nsr/logs
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:23 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:30 PM /nsr/lost+found
                       107087992 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:09:39 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:10:49 PM /nsr/nmc/nmcdb
                        87359588 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:12:48 PM                                    full AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:13:56 PM /nsr/nmc/nmcdb_stage
                            3360 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL-TEMP                    cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:08:08 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:09:12 PM /nsr/tmp
                            3360 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:39 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:44 PM /nsr/tmp
                               4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com        vF                                      AWS-FS-BKP-DUPL                         cb                                                        10/05/2018 07:11:18 PM                                    incr AU-AWS-FS-BKP-001                                        10/05/2018 07:12:22 PM /root
```

I am trying to parse the output using split method. I tried to split using space but it doesn't give me the correct output.
I tried following piece of code to split:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
string[] lines = text.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
lines = lines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    formatedop = Regex.Split(item, @"\s{3,}");
    //formatedop = item.Split('\t');
    formatedop = formatedop.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
}
```

I want output in the following format:

```
formatedop[0]=290502556
formatedop[1]=awsnwkip01
formatedop[1]=vrF
formatedop[2]=BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION
formatedop[3]=cr
formatedop[4]=10/05/2018 07:56:29 PM
formatedop[5]=full
formatedop[6]=AFTD-Bootstrap-00
formatedop[7]=10/05/2018 07:56:36 PM
formatedop[8]=bootstrap
```

Comment: You are aware that your output uses the [1] twice?

Comment: OK, so that's the output that you *want*. What's the output that you *get*?

Comment: @TomTom..yes i know..thats dummy output

Comment: @DavidZemens..I am getting the following output
formatedop[0]=290502556 awsnwkip01
formatedop[1]=vrF
formatedop[2]=BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION
formatedop[3]=cr
formatedop[4]=10/05/2018 07:56:29 PM
formatedop[5]=full AFTD-Bootstrap-00
formatedop[6]=10/05/2018 07:56:36 PM bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it was suppose to be fix width columns but some fields are larger which causes issues.  I was able to parse using regex.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (++lineNumber > 1)
                {
                    clients.Add(new Client(line));
                }
            }


        }
    }
    public class Client
    {
        public long size { get; set; }
        public string client { get; set; }
        public string ssflags { get; set; }
        public string group { get; set; }
        public string flags { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
        public DateTime completed { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public Client(string line)
        {
            string pattern = @"^\s*(?'size'[^\s]+)\s+(?'client'[^\s]+)\s+(?'ssflags'[^\s]+)\s+" +
                @"(?'group'.*)\s+(?'flags'cr|cb)\s+(?'date'.+(AM|PM))\s+" +
                @"(?'level'[^\s]+)\s+(?'volume'[^\s]+)\s+" +
                @"(?'completed'.+(AM|PM))\s+(?'name'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);

            size = long.Parse(match.Groups["size"].Value);
            client = match.Groups["client"].Value;
            ssflags = match.Groups["ssflags"].Value;
            group = match.Groups["group"].Value.Trim();
            flags = match.Groups["flags"].Value;

            date = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups["date"].Value);
            level = match.Groups["level"].Value;
            volume = match.Groups["volume"].Value;
            completed = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups["completed"].Value);
            name = match.Groups["name"].Value;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats clean bro

Comment: I always use a variable name with groups to make my Regex more understandable.

Comment: @jdweng..Thanks for your response but its not working properly. It breaks for some or the other value. Eg: completed = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups["completed"].Value); it is expecting datetime value but it gives some string value.- "AWS - FS - BKP - 001"

Comment: Can you list all the values being returned when it is not a DateTime?  I think the DateTime field is empty and it is trying to parse the 'name' field  as a DateTime.

Comment: @jdweng..No as of now i can see only this value being returned. DateTime value is present its not empty. Can you please refine the regex so that it gives the correct output.

Comment: I need a sample of a bad line.  I looks like the volume is being returned for date which means there must be something different earlier in the line that is causing the issue.   Possibly a space in the volume or the level may be two words.

Comment: @jdweng..This is the line which is creating issue
290502556 artykrtp0o vrF                                     BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION                    cr                                                        10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:29 PM full AFTD - Bootstrap - 00                                        10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:36 PM bootstrap

Volum should be AFTD - Bootstrap - 00

Comment: When you put the line into a comment the spacing gets changed so I do'n see the issue.  I took you  original posting and it is working the way I expect it to work.  I added to my answer a scree shot of the parsed row so you can see what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have single space characters in your strings that you want to keep (e.g."10/05/2018 07:56:36 PM") but in other places single space characters that are used as separators (e.g."4 awsn.ad.broadrum.com"), one quick and easy way would be to do s.th. like this (note the two space characters in the string separator!):

```
var result = line[1].Split(new string[]{"  "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();
```

This will give you this:

List(5) { " 290502556 awsknwpi00 vrF", " BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION", "cr", "10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:29 PM full AFTD - Bootstrap - 00", "10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:36 PM bootstrap" }

Then you can split the first item further down by single space character and insert the output of that operation at index 1 and remove the unsplit version at index 0, s.th. like this:

```
result.InsertRange(1, result[0].Split(' '));
result.RemoveAt(0);
```

This will give you s.th. like this:

List(8) { "", "290502556", "awsknwpi00", "vrF", " BOOTSTRAP PROTECTION", "cr", "10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:29 PM full AFTD - Bootstrap - 00", "10 / 05 / 2018 07:56:36 PM bootstrap" }

As you can see you might have to iterate through and do some additional trimming, but that's a start.

Comment: you can wrap this up into a nice lambda expression, iterate through for calling .Trim() and for throwing out the emtpy string that made its way into the result

Comment: will not work since some groups have a space in the middle and other do not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use This:

```
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    formatedop = imem.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: Will not work since name and group have spaces in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I've used in the past a good library named FileHelpers (https://www.filehelpers.net).
It allows you parse files delimited by known symbols and files with fixed lenght fields. I cannot tell if the latter is your case (I don't think so from what you've pasted, but it could be a copy/paste issue)
There is also another feature called Smart format detector (described here: https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/SmartFormatDetector/) which you can try to see if it resolves your problem.
The library is really easy to use, I encourage you to give it a try.